# why data of xml file does not transform to html using xslt

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I try to display the data of xml file into html table but when I link the xml file with xsl file the result in the web browser is:

> Mohammed 2000  Nasr 2000  Ahamed 2000

I read all the related questions in stack but no answer guide me.
anyone can help and I appreciate any help.

the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="xml.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<emps>
<emp>
    <ename>Mohammed</ename>
    <esal>2000</esal>
</emp>
<emp>
    <ename>Nasr</ename>
    <esal>2000</esal>
</emp>
<emp>
    <ename>Ahamed</ename>
    <esal>2000</esal>
</emp>
</emps>
```

the xsl file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
<html>
<body>
<xsl:template match="/">
<table>
    <xsl:for-each select="emp">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="emps/ename"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="/esal"/></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>

</table>
</xsl:template>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: change `<xsl:for-each select="emp">` to `<xsl:for-each select="emps">` and `<xsl:value-of select="emps/ename"/>` to `<xsl:value-of select="emp/ename"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Your xslt is not well formed. Have a look at the following, changed XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="emps"/>                
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="emps">
        <table>
            <xsl:for-each select="emp">
                <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="ename"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="esal"/></td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```